# Do I need caching in my node.js app

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am making a simple app in node.js and socket.io. The thing I am aiming for is response speed. User types and on each keypress gets results FAST. Number of records in the database: about 100k to start with. The records will be rarely changing.

Its setup like : 
receive data from browser via socket.io , do a sphinx search, do a mysql query. and send the data back to the browser via socket.emit. Simple!

Will this setup benefit from any kind of caching? I don't about the intricacies of caching but  memcache/redis seem like an overkill.
Its just a hobby learning project btw

Comment: Rather difficult to say if it would benefit from caching. I would suggest: just create your basic app, see how its performance is, and only if there are any bottlenecks, think about how to mitigate them.